# ActiveXObject или есть аналогия?

Tags: javascript, textarea

Клиенту дается страница с текстовым блоком `textarea`. Как можно через jquery (или дайте ссылку на какую то библиотеку) сохранить текст из текстового блока в текстовый документ?

Internet Explorer не подходит, поскольку делается под андроид (приложение)

Answer (score 1):

Обычно для решения подобных задач с помощью *jQuery* используется [generateFile](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/05/generating-files-javascript-php/). Можно ещё попробовать воспользоваться функционалом *HTML5* (*FileSystem API* и *FileAPI*). Однако, так как речь идёт о мобильных браузерах, нечего гарантировать не могу.

Comment: к сожалению не работает, даже попытался сделать [это](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121417/can-i-use-jquery-to-create-a-file-and-its-content-dynamically)  но оно не сохраняет там где мне надо. А еще возможно ли считать как то из txt файла